# Different binwidth for each plot in FacetGrid Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, facet

I would like to give each `histplot` in `FacetGrid` from `seaborn` a different `binwidth`. To give each plot a `binwidth` of 3 is possible like this:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="day", height=3.5, aspect=.65)
g.map(sns.histplot, "total_bill", binwidth = 3)
```

Output:

[image]

But let's say you want to give each plot a different `binwidth`, for example 1,2,3 and 4 in a list, the following error appears:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="day", height=3.5, aspect=.65)
g.map(sns.histplot, "total_bill", binwidth = [1,2,3,4])
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to give each plot in the `FacetGrid` a different `binwidth` using `seaborn`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop simultaneously through `g.axes_dict` and the widths, and call the function separately for each subplot. You'll need to manually create the correct subset of the dataframe.

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="day", height=3.5, aspect=.65)
for (day, ax), binwidth in zip(g.axes_dict.items(), [1, 2, 3, 4]):
    sns.histplot(tips[tips["day"] == day]['total_bill'], binwidth=binwidth, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(f'day={day} binwidth={binwidth}')
```

[image: sns.FacetGrid with individual parameters]